# Get product id and product type in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am creating magento store. I am beginner in magento.  I want to get product id and product input type in my phtml file is this possible? please guide me..

I am trying to this way to get product type. but its not working for me

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$productType=$product->getTypeID();
```

Please guide me...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try below code to get currently loaded product id:

```
$product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
```

When you don’t have access to $this, you can use Magento registry:

```
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
```

Also for product type i think

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 

$productType = $product->getTypeId();
```

Comment: Hi @liyakat. I got it my product id. i need also get product type. please help mei am trying $_product->getResource()->getTypeId() this way but i got Fatal error: Call to a member function getCategoryIds() on a non-object

Comment: This is my demo url http://demo.osiztechnologies.com/printing/index.php/folders/9x14-5-folders

Comment: Thanks for your answers. my last question i am creating custom option input type using config.xml file. admin panel custom option tab working good. it show web2print option. but i am save that option type. any possible to get input type in magento please guide me..

Comment: I got product id and product type. last question only please help me

Comment: i am not getting you clear about custom option ? is it from admin side or front end to get from end user ? will you please explain more

Comment: custom option in admin side. please see this url http://demo.osiztechnologies.com/printing/index.php/folders/9x14-5-folders. My task is add web2print tool in magento. but the tool in core php so i am add one menu in admin panel called web2print also i can go to admin page catalog-> managecatelog->customoption. i am also creating new input type like(File/text). my type name called web2print

Comment: This is my ref URl for create custom options http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/custom-input-types-custom-options

Comment: Hey @liyakat , how can i get child id from product id ?

Comment: Thanks! You save my day!

I had a lot of problems with attributes in files different from view.phtml... with your Mage::registry now i have solved all problems!

Comment: @liyakat the function name is `getTypeId()` not `getTypeID()`. You also have  `‘` and `’` quotes in your second code block.

Comment: @liyakat How can i get add to cart button in my CMS page for relevant products?

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'simple' ): ?>
//your code for simple products only
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped' ): ?>
//your code for grouped products only
<?php endif; ?>
```

So on.
It works! Magento 1.6.1, place in the view.phtml

Answer (score 3):

you can get all product information from following code

```
$product_id=6//Suppose
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);


    $product_data["id"]=$_product->getId();
    $product_data["name"]=$_product->getName();
    $product_data["short_description"]=$_product->getShortDescription();
    $product_data["description"]=$_product->getDescription();
    $product_data["price"]=$_product->getPrice();
    $product_data["special price"]=$_product->getFinalPrice();
    $product_data["image"]=$_product->getThumbnailUrl();
    $product_data["model"]=$_product->getSku();
    $product_data["color"]=$_product->getAttributeText('color'); //get cusom attribute value


    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->setStoreId($storeId)  ->load($_product->getId());
    $product_data["rating"]=($summaryData['rating_summary']*5)/100;

    $product_data["shipping"]=Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/flatrate/price');

    if($_product->isSalable() ==1)
        $product_data["in_stock"]=1;
    else
        $product_data["in_stock"]=0;


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($product_data);
    //echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I want how can i get input type name or id. guide me

Comment: This answered the question I have when I came here so upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

**Item collection.**

```
$_item->product_type;
$_item->getId()
```

**Product :**

```
$product->getTypeId();
$product->getId()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this..

> $this->getProduct()->getId();

When you don’t have access to $this you can use Magento registry:

> $cpid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();

Answer (score 0):

IN MAGENTO query in the database and fetch the result like. 
product id, product name and manufracturer
with out using the product flat table 
use the eav catalog_product_entity and its attribute table
product_id    product_name     manufacturer
    1 |      PRODUCTA |          NOKIA
    2 |      PRODUCTB |          SAMSUNG

Answer (score 0):

`$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);`

above code not working for me. its throw exception;

This is working for me for get product details.

`$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product = $obj->load($product_id);`

So use for for product type.

`$productType = $_product->getTypeId();`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me-

```
if(Mage::registry('current_product')->getTypeId() == 'simple' ) {
```

Use `getTypeId()`