# Add product to cart with ID specified

Tags: php, magento

So I need to include an add to cart button on a cms page so I'm trying to do this through a template block file in php. I can't figure out how to do this for just one static product though.

So the code for the usual add to cart button on product pages looks like this:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="btn-add-box">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="btn btn-warning add-to-cart" style="margin-top:6px;width:200px;margin-left:20px;" data-url="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product, ['_secure' => true]) ?>" onclick="ga('ec:setAction', 'add'); ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'add to cart');"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But how do I do this for just the product with the ID 33? So I only want to display an add to cart button that adds the product with this ID on a static page. I've tried using a url on the cms page so like http://testing.co.uk/checkout/cart/add?product=[33]&qty=[1] but this just goes to the cart, but doesn't add the product.

Comment: Well instead of `$this->getProduct()`, use a method to actually get a product by the id you specify ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/16331887/1427878

Answer (score 0):

// Try with following code.

```
$_productId = '33';
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$_url = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); 


<a href="<?php echo $_url ?>">Add To Cart</a>
```